# AWK Converting a "long date" to datetime

Tags: date, twitter, awk, gawk

I tried to find the answer on here and other sources but I'm at a loss. I'm building a little tiny awk-tool to use with the console based twitter client twidge (https://github.com/jgoerzen/twidge/wiki‎)

From the output of the incoming tweets I want to do various cool stuff but for the data to be useful I need to first get the timestamp into a format I can handle.

For reference, Here's the output I'm currently getting with the command

Code

```
twidge lsrecent -l | gawk -F"\t" '{print "@"$2 ": " $4 " ("$5")"}'
```

Output

```
@nytimes: China Cuts Ties With North Korean Bank http://t.co/N3iljjgGbH (Tue May 07 12:57:04 +0000 2013)
```

Then I tried to be clever and did this

Code

```
twidge lsrecent -l | gawk -F"\t" '{print "@"$2 ": " $4 " ("strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",$5)")"}'
```

But got this unfortunate output

```
@BloombergNews: HSBC posts bigger-than-estimated increase in first-quarter profit | http://t.co/QraWonRU32 (1970-01-01 01:00:00)
```

As we can see, the date conversion was not as hoped. Any pointers most welcome. It doesn't have to be awk/gawk it's just a preference. Ultimately the data will be put into a database and worked on there.

Thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the external date command.(I just make example for the dateString);

```
kent$  echo "Tue May 07 12:57:04 +0000 2013"|awk '{"date -d\""$0"\" +\"%F %T\""|getline d; print d}'
2013-05-07 14:57:04
```

or get the date in seconds since 1970-01-01 utc, then use awk's strftime:

```
awk '{"date -d\""$0"\" +\"%s\""|getline d; print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",d)}'
```

**EDIT**

```
twidge lsrecent -l | gawk -F"\t" '{"date -d\""$5"\" +\"%s\""|getline d;print "@"$2 ": " $4 " ("strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T",d)")"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried but this is what happened
`@ReutersBiz: OfficeMax shares up as special dividend outweighs profit miss http://t.co/LlR6yK4N8l( date -d"Tue May 07 13:30:32 +0000 2013" +"%F %T" )`
from command 
`:~/scripts$ twidge lsrecent -l | gawk -F"\t" '{print "@"$2 ": " $4 "( ""date -d\""$5"\" +\"%F %T\""" )"}'`

Comment: I have a `getline` in my code. you just concatenate a string with `date -d.....`, didn't execute it.

Comment: ok, so then my question becomes how to execute `date`within an awk-script

Comment: if you really want to parse the datestring with awk and use `mktime()` function, it works too. using `date` cmd is just simpler. (my opinion. )

Comment: I get your example to work naturally. But in my script where I want to  do the conversion inline I don't get how to implement the same code.